# Are you allowed to take pictures inside the Tomb of Ramesses?

Tags: photography, egypt

Are you allowed to take pictures inside the Tomb of Ramesses and other underground, painted tombs in the Valley of the Kings in Egypt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_of_the_Kings) says

> Photography is no longer allowed in the tombs.

Searching [Frommer's](https://books.google.ca/books?id=lGisBVIN9bUC&pg=PA275&lpg=PA275&dq=photography&source=bl&ots=s_1ITDE045&sig=t06dfc2DS8JnnNRqkezy4fZ_deA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vS0PVbaAIMT2oASL3YJo&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCw#v=snippet&q=photography%20&f=false) also indicates this being the case.

Another [page](http://www.scaruffi.com/travel/egypt.html) which even mentions that in Saqqara you can bribe the guards with a few pounds only says

> But they all pale compared with Ramses VI, which is 50 EP by itself. RIPOFF ALTER: no photos are allowed inside the tombs. Valley of the Kings is invariably a disappointment because there is very little to see, even less that is truly impressive, lots of tourists and no photography allowed.